# Creating URL from html string (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, nsurl

I have to load an small HTML part in my iOS app.
I could save it in a file and load the URL using the filePath

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "HTML")
```

But my HTML has a variable so I need it to be dynamic.
So I want to create an URL from the HTML as a string.

```
let htmlString = """
<div>.....</div>
"""
```

I tried different initialisers like URL(string: htmlString) or URL(data: Data(htmlString.utf8)) but they don't work.
Anyway I can achieve this ?

*Not interested in using the direct method of WKWebView.

Comment: How is HTML and URL the same thing? What do you mean when you say you want to create an url from html code?

Comment: You could save your dynamically created html to a temporary file and then load that from a file url, but that is just overcomplicating matters.  If your intent is to deliver the HTML to a `WKWebView` then [just do that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415011-load); No need for a URL.

Comment: That was my first thought too , but wasn't sure how safe that solution is to keep writing on that one file. I have a custom solution for loading the WKWebView through a NSRequest instead of using the string directly that's why I try avoiding that.

Comment: If you want to use a URL, a *Uniform Resource Locator* then you have to have a resource to locate - You will need to create a temp file and use a URL that points to that.  Your current question confuses a resource location with resource content

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load web content into a `WKWebView` from memory, create the web view and call `load(_:mimeType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:)` to load the content from memory. That's what that method is for.

Otherwise you will need to save your content to a local file, (probably in your app's caches directory) build a file URL to that file, and then load that into your web view using `loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)`